# QuadEdge dual edge coordinate's always the origin

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry, triangulation, voronoi, delaunay

I am trying to implement, in Javascript, a divide and conquer algorithm to calculate a Delanay triangulation, in order to obtain a Voronoi diagram. The coded is based on the C++ implementation described in Graphic Gems IV which, in turn, is based on the famous Guibas and Stolfi paper from 1985. It uses a Quad-Edge data structure.

The algorithm divides the set of points in half; then, it triangulates those parts separately; lastly it proceeds to "marry" the two halves.

The problem is that, well, it does not work. It gets stuck in a infinite recursion when "marrying" the two halves. I *think* the problem might be in the Quad-Edge structure itself, because the first edge's and its destination edge have the same coordinates and its dual and inverted rotation edge point to (0, 0).

Here is the code (the translation from C++ is not 100 %, I asked for help since I am still a JS noob):

```
    //The data structure starts here.
    var Edge = function (num, qe) {
    var _this = this;
    this.num = num;
    this.qe = qe;
    this.coord = new paper.Point();

    this.sym = function () {
        return (_this.num < 2) ? _this.qe[_this.num + 2] : this.qe[_this.num - 2];
    };

    this.oNext = function () {
        return this.next;
    };

    this.setNext = function (next) {
        this.next = next
    };

    this.rot = function () {
        return (this.num < 3) ? _this.qe[_this.num + 1] : _this.qe[_this.num - 3];
    };

    this.invRot = function () {
        return (_this.num > 0) ? _this.qe[_this.num - 1] : _this.qe[_this.num + 3];
    };

    this.oPrev = function () {
        return _this.rot().oNext().rot();
    };

    this.dNext = function () {
        return _this.sym().next.sym();
    };

    this.dPrev = function () {
        return _this.invRot().oNext().invRot();
    };

    this.lNext = function () {
        return _this.invRot().oNext().rot();
    };

    this.lPrev = function () {
        return _this.oNext().sym();
    };

    this.rNext = function () {
        return _this.rot().oNext().invRot();
    };

    this.rPrev = function () {
        return _this.sym().oNext();
    };

    this.dest = function () {
        return _this.sym().coord;
    };

    this.endPoints = function (or, de) {
        this.coord = or;
        this.sym().coord = de;
    };
};

//The first edge always points to itself
//as in edge.oNext().coord === edge.coord
var QuadEdge = function () {
    this.edges = new Array(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.edges[i] = new Edge(i, this.edges);
    }
    this.edges[0].setNext(this.edges[0]);
    this.edges[1].setNext(this.edges[3]);
    this.edges[2].setNext(this.edges[2]);
    this.edges[3].setNext(this.edges[1]);
};
//Constructs and returns a new QuadEdge.
function makeEdge() {
    var qe = new QuadEdge();
    return qe.edges[0];
}
//Helper function, returns twice of the area of the triangle formed
//by a, b and c. Negative if the triangle is clockwise.
function triArea(a, b, c) {
    return (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (c.x - a.x) * (b.y - a.y);
}
//Tests if the point d is inside the circumcircle of the triangle formed by
//a, b, and c. As described by Guibas and Stolfi in their paper.
function inCircle(a, b, c, d) {
    return (Math.pow(a.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y, 2)) * triArea(b, c, d) -
        (Math.pow(b.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y, 2)) * triArea(a, c, d) +
        (Math.pow(c.x, 2) + Math.pow(c.y, 2)) * triArea(a, b, d) -
        (Math.pow(d.x, 2) + Math.pow(d.y, 2)) * triArea(a, b, d) > 0;
}
//Tests if triangle is in counterclockwise order.
function cClockwise(a, b, c) {
    return triArea(a, b, c) > 0;
}
//Tests if point is left of the provided edge.
function leftOf(point, edge) {
    return cClockwise(point, edge.coord, edge.dest());
}
//Tests if point is right of the provided edge.
function rightOf(point, edge) {
    return cClockwise(point, edge.dest(), edge.coord);
}
//If a and b are distinct, splice will combine them; if not, it will
//separate them in two. 
function splice(a, b) {
    var alpha = a.oNext().rot();
    var beta = b.oNext().rot();

    var t1 = b.oNext();
    var t2 = a.oNext();
    var t3 = beta.oNext();
    var t4 = alpha.oNext();

    a.setNext(t1);
    b.setNext(t2);
    alpha.setNext(t3);
    beta.setNext(t4);
}

function deleteEdge(e) {
    splice(e, e.oPrev());
    splice(e.sym(), e.sym().oPrev());
}

function connect(e1, e2) {
    var e = makeEdge();
    e.endPoints(e1.dest(), e2.coord);
    splice(e, e1.lNext());
    splice(e.sym(), e2);
    return e;
}

//Fixed thanks to: http://www.rpenalva.com/blog/?p=74
function valid(e, basel) {
    return rightOf(e.dest(), basel);
}
//This is the actual algorithm.
function divideAndConquer(vertices) {
    if (vertices.length === 2) {
        var a = makeEdge();
        a.coord = vertices[0];
        a.sym().coord = vertices[1];
        return {right: a, left: a.sym()};
    }
    else if (vertices.length === 3) {
        var a = makeEdge(), b = makeEdge();
        splice(a.sym(), b);
        a.coord = vertices[0];
        b.coord = vertices[1];
        a.sym().coord = b.coord;
        b.sym().coord = vertices[2];

        if (cClockwise(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2])) {
            connect(b, a);
            return {right: a, left: b.sym()};
        }
        else if (cClockwise(vertices[0], vertices[2], vertices[1])) {
            var c = connect(b, a);
            return {right: c.sym(), left: c};
        }
        else
            return {right: a, left: b.sym()};
    }
    else if (vertices.length >= 4) {
        var half = Math.floor(vertices.length / 2);
        var lObjects = divideAndConquer(vertices.slice(0, half));
        var rObjects = divideAndConquer(vertices.slice(half, vertices.length));
        var ldo = lObjects.right, ldi = lObjects.left;
        var rdi = rObjects.right, rdo = rObjects.left;

        while (true) {
            if (leftOf(rdi.coord, ldi))
                ldi = ldi.lNext();
            else if (rightOf(ldi.coord, rdi))
                rdi = rdi.rPrev();
            else
                break;
        }

        var basel = connect(rdi.sym(), ldi);
        if (ldi.coord === ldo.coord)
            ldo = basel.sym();
        if (rdi.coord === rdo.coord)
            rdo = basel;
        while (true) {
            var lcand = basel.sym().oNext();
            if (valid(lcand, basel)) {
                while (inCircle(basel.dest(), basel.coord, lcand.dest(), lcand.oPrev().dest())) {
                    var t = lcand.oNext();
                    deleteEdge(lcand);
                    lcand = t;
                }
            }
            var rcand = basel.oPrev();
            if (valid(rcand, basel)) {
                while (inCircle(basel.dest(), basel.coord, rcand.dest(), rcand.oPrev().dest())) {
                    var t = rcand.oPrev();
                    deleteEdge(rcand);
                    rcand = t;
                }
            }
            //This is the part where it gets stuck,
            //it never reaches this condition.
            if (!valid(lcand, basel) && !valid(rcand, basel)) {
                break;
            }
            if (!valid(lcand, basel) || (valid(rcand, basel) && inCircle(lcand.dest(), lcand.coord, rcand.coord, rcand.dest()))) {
                basel = connect(rcand, basel.sym());
            }
            else {
                basel = connect(basel.sym(), lcand.sym());
            }
        }
        return {right: ldo, left: rdo};
    }
}
```

The point class is from [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org).

**EDIT:** set up a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tercept/pen/BpmPeK) illustrating the problem; click in the output window to add the points. The recursions happens when the fourth point is added.

**EDIT 2:** fixed the infinite recursion, caused by the valid function, thanks to code found on Ruben Penalva's [blog](http://www.rpenalva.com/blog/?p=74). But, the problem of the dual edge pointing to the origin still persists. That is:

```
edge.rot().coord === (0, 0)
```

That makes me think even more that the problem is with the QuadEdge structure itself.

**EDIT 3:** reading the code carefully for the nth time, I realized that the coordinates for the rotation and inversed rotation edge are never set. So I tried setting them by rotating the original edge. The output now draws *something*, though I'm pretty sure thats not a Delaunay triangulation. I updated the Codepen example with the progress.

Comment: Please provide a full example of inputs that cause the problem.

Comment: Done, added a Codepen example.